# Stop the re-render of chats

Tags: javascript, typescript, stenciljs

I am facing a problem related to the re-rendering process in chat-bot. Here is the problem:

I have created a function that returns a string (HTML supported), which will be formatted like an HTML. So here is the utils.ts:

```
export function formaterForUi(text: string) {

function Video() {
    formattedMessage = text.replace(/\!\[Video\]\((((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+))/gi,
      function (fullText) {
        let fromHttp = fullText.substring(9)
        return fromHttp.replace(/((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+)/gi,
          function (videoURLWithLastCharacter) {
            let videoUrl = videoURLWithLastCharacter.substring(0, videoURLWithLastCharacter.length - 1);
            return '<div style="max-width: 600px; margin:7px 0px;"><video style="height: auto; width:100%;" controls><source src="' + videoUrl + '" type="video/mp4"></video></div>'
          })
      });
  }

vedio();

return formattedMessage;
}
```

This function will find the mentioned regex from the input string and format it as a video in HTML(GUI).

So here is the main .tsx file in a stencil.

```
formatChatMessages() {
      let count = 0
      while (count < this.chats.length) {
         this.chatBubbleElement.shadowRoot.querySelector("#chat-id-" + (count)).innerHTML = formaterForUi(this.chats[count].message, this.sorryMessageArray)
        count++
      }
  }
```

Here, there are multiple video chats responses, so every time this function will format them that a browser can support. **"chats" is the array, that contain all the responses**

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.formatChatMessages()
   }
```

Ans I am calling this particular function(formatChatMessages()) in ComponentDidUpdate life cycle. So every time I type something in textbox it will re-render all the video-chats for the fraction of time. You can see requests are kept sending in the Network tab in Developer tools in Chrome.

As an expected result, I want to stop the re-rendering of the video every time and it will not format the other chats if I don't call it in componentDidUpdate.

Please provide Solution here

Comment: Could you please clarify what your actual question is? Also, have a look at the State decorator (https://stenciljs.com/docs/state).

Comment: @SimonHänisch Here video keeps re-rendering because I am calling the 'formatChatMessages' function in 'componentDidUpdate'. I want to load the video once.

Comment: Post all code not just fragments - it may be important to know what things are `@Prop`, `@State`, etc. in order to offer a solution.